# Delete Wall Post on page as page C# SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to delete the post as page.
I already have access token of the admin user and access token from the page.

My Code:

```
var fbClient = new FacebookClient { AccessToken = getPageAccessToken() };

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

parameters.id = postId;

fbClient.Delete(m_GroupId + "/feed",parameters);
```

I get the following error:

```
 {"error":
    {
       "type":"OAuthException",
       "message":"Invalid token: \"PAGE_ID\".  An ID has already been specified."
    }
  }
```

I replaced the page id above with PAGE_ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the page access token and pass the post id as the path for Delete method.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("pageAccessToken");
fb.Delete(postId);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the C# SDK, but from the look of it you're setting the ID twice, once with parameters.id and again with m_GroupID

Comment: yea but I thought I need the ID of the group (or page) and the id of the post I want to delete

Comment: @Niyo Not really, you just need to issue a `DELETE` request to the post object you want to delete (cf the doc). Feels like you're jumping through hoops for a basic operation here